# CSS selector to exclude contents of a DIV element?

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <img src="path/to/image.jpg" />
  <div class="product">
    <p>Dolor sit amet</p>
    <img src="path/to/another/image.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I need a CSS selector to select and style the first image (the one in the .content div element) but NOT the second one (the one in the .product div element).

I have gone a few rounds with the :not() negation pseudo class, but something like

```
.content *:not(.product) img
```

doesn't seem to be working (probably because I've bastardized the syntax).

How can I select all images anywhere in my .content div, but excluse all images anywhere in my .product divs? Note that multiple divs may be nested at various levels, so I can't refer to a specific child of a .content div.

Comment: Have you tried `.content > img`?

Comment: Find the correct solution, also for your requirement with the nested containers, in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.content > img` to only select direct children of `.content`

This won't include the images inside `.product`.

Comment: Any docs or more information on why this works is always good. But the answer is correct, though.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanWensveen, happy to help. Could you mark my answer as correct then?

Comment: "Note that multiple divs may be nested at various levels, so I can't refer to a specific child of a .content div." vs. "Yep. That's the one!". This is highly contradictory.

Comment: @connexo Thanks, I am aware of that. OP's question would suggest a more detailed answer, however in this scenario my answer suffices.  I will edit my answer to expand on your comments.

Comment: That is not necessary as the corect answers are already in place.

Answer (score 4):

The first image is not matched by your selector because it requires to have an element as intermediate level between `.content` and `img` (and whose class must not be `.product`) so you could write instead

```
:not(.product) > img {

}
```

Comment: Probably OP rather needs `.content > img, .content *:not(.product) > img { ... } ` since I bet those won't be the only images on the site and he probably doesn't want to target them *all*.

Answer (score 3):

What you need actually requires *two* selectors, one of which you already have. That one must be complemented by another one that also finds direct child `img` of `.content`:

```
.content > img, .content *:not(.product) > img { ... }
```

Comment: Good answer ! But there are corner cases not covered .. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `.content >img`. This will hopefully work for you.

Comment: Any docs or more information on why this works is always good. But the answer is correct, though.

Comment: This is because `>` is a child element selector to 1st level children only

Comment: _I know that_. Does the person reading your answer? It would improve your answer to add such things.

Answer (score 1):

Your `not` selector is not quite doing what you want;

```
.content *:not(.product) img
```

is selecting images that are children of any elements except those with `class="product"`, who are *themselves* children of elements with `class="content"`.

However, in your code, the image you want to select is not a *grandchild* of `.content`; it's a *direct* child. Assuming your markup structure will not be changing, you can use the [direct descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to achieve what you want:

```
.content > img {}
```

Alternatively, you can give the images you want to select a class name, and just select that class, like:

```
<img class="contentImg">

.contentImg {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need as many rules as levels can be between the .content and the image

```css
.content > span,
.content > :not(.product) > span,
.content > :not(.product) > :not(.product) > span,
.content > :not(.product) > :not(.product) > :not(.product) > span
{
  background-color: lightblue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <span>YES</span>
  <div class="product">
    <p>Dolor sit amet</p>
    <span>NO</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with solutions like

```
.content *:not(.product) > img { ... }
```

is that it will match the sequence of descendants

```
.content > .product > anything > img
```

Answer (score -2):

**Try this:**

HTML:
Added **id="image1"**

```
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <img id="image1" src="path/to/image.jpg" />
   <div class="product">
    <p>Dolor sit amet</p>
    <img src="path/to/another/image.jpg" />
  </div>
```

CSS: Added ID selector

```
#image1{
width:100% (example)

};
```

Comment: This would not work because Frank is asking how to select *all* images that are children of `.content`. IDs can only be selected one at a time, since they must be unique.

Comment: _I need a CSS selector to select and style the first image_

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the question, which begins *"How can I select all images anywhere in my .content div"*